# Chrome crashes immediately after opening

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome immediately crashes as soon as it's opened giving the generic error `Google Chrome quit unexpectedly`.

Tried launching with extensions disabled, but that doesn't help:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --disable-extensions
```

Tried reinstalling Chrome and restarting computer. Neither helps.

How do I figure out what is breaking it?

Comment: Broken profile? Try creating a new chrome profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem occur today on a Mac as well. Not sure what the original cause was, but the problem is a corrupt profile. A good fix would be the following:

1. Open a terminal.
2. Find your Chrome folder. For our Mac, this was `Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome`, so navigate to `cd Users/<username>/Library/Application\ Support/Google/`.
3. Do `mv Chrome/ ChromeOld/` to force Chrome to rebuild the profile on next run.
4. Run Chrome and perform your standard first-run setup steps. *Reenable / install your extensions one at a time* and restart Chrome after each to isolate which extension might be causing a problem, if any.

Hopefully this solution works for you as well.